# Java IF Statement Evaluation Order

Tags: java, if-statement

I am working on Assignment 7 for MIT's Intro to Java course. The assignment is to build a Magic Squares evaluator. My code is working ok but I don't understand why halfway through evaluating the input file the order of execution of the IF statements flips (according to my console output in Eclipse).

```
for (String part : parts) {
            try {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(part);
                sum2 = otherChecks.get(itemNumber) + Integer.parseInt(part);
                otherChecks.set(itemNumber, sum2);

                if (itemNumber == rowNumber){
                    sum2 = otherChecks.get(otherChecks.size()-2) + Integer.parseInt(part);
                    otherChecks.set(otherChecks.size()-2, sum2);
                    System.out.println("diag forward " + part +" item and row numbers " + itemNumber + ","+ rowNumber);
                }
                if (itemNumber == parts.length - rowNumber - 1 ){
                    sum2 = otherChecks.get(otherChecks.size()-1) + Integer.parseInt(part);
                    otherChecks.set(otherChecks.size()-1, sum2);
                    System.out.println("diag backward " + part +" item and row numbers " + itemNumber + ","+ rowNumber);
                }
                itemNumber++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException err) {
                System.out.println("Skipping Line");
                sum = lastSum;
                rowNumber --;
            }
        }
```

This is the file being read into java:

```
8   58  59  5   4   62  63  1

49  15  14  52  53  11  10  56

41  23  22  44  45  19  18  48

32  34  35  29  28  38  39  25

40  26  27  37  36  30  31  33

17  47  46  20  21  43  42  24

9   55  54  12  13  51  50  16

64  2   3   61  60  6   7   57
```

And the output. Line skips are the lines without numbers that throw an exception that is being caught as evidenced by "Skipping Line" in the output.

```
diag forward 8 item and row numbers 0,0
diag backward 1 item and row numbers 7,0

Skipping Line
diag forward 15 item and row numbers 1,1
diag backward 10 item and row numbers 6,1
Skipping Line
diag forward 22 item and row numbers 2,2
diag backward 19 item and row numbers 5,2
Skipping Line
diag forward 29 item and row numbers 3,3
diag backward 28 item and row numbers 4,3
Skipping Line
diag backward 37 item and row numbers 3,4
diag forward 36 item and row numbers 4,4
Skipping Line
diag backward 46 item and row numbers 2,5
diag forward 43 item and row numbers 5,5
Skipping Line
diag backward 55 item and row numbers 1,6
diag forward 50 item and row numbers 6,6
Skipping Line
diag backward 64 item and row numbers 0,7
diag forward 57 item and row numbers 7,7
```

And explaining this I see where my assumption failed. Thanks to Hot Licks in the comments.
Thanks and sorry

Comment: What statement? What output?

Comment: We're going to need a sample of your output if you want us to help you debug this.

Comment: "the order of execution of the IF statements flips": Nobody but you knows what you mean by this.

Comment: We need more informations about problem you want to solve. Posting example of input, expected output and actual (problematic) output would be helpful. For now it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Try putting a print statement each time at the start of the loop...(or using a debugger and stepping through it).

Comment: Halfway through you start failing the first if test.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by seeing that your question was put on hold. We can vote to reopen it if you [[edit]] it and add more details about problem you are facing.

Comment: I see it now. I was really out to lunch on this one. Down vote at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in a loop.  If you're running this in a debugger, you'll see it skip the items in the first "if" and go to the second in some cases.  It's still traversing the loop.  Set up a watch on "part" and it should be clearer.

Note, you're probably getting downvoted because this is more of a school question than usually is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Once I move to the bottom half of the square, the upward (from left to right) diagonal gets picked up before the downward diagonal from the magic square.